# Tengo que acomodar un DIV

Tags: html, css

Tengo que acomodar unos *div* que estoy usando como botones alineados al final del container.
[image: Divs a acomodar]

La idea sería que queden aproximadamente a la altura del botón de la izquierda los 3.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="cardcontainer">
  <div class="card">
    {content1}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    {content2}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    {content3}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cardcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  box-shadow: var(--shadows);
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.card h2 {
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
  font-size: var(--font-size-2);
}

.button {
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.button img {
  max-width: 20px;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias a quien me ayude!!

Comment: No funcionó. No sucedió absolutamente nada :(

Comment: Prueba poniéndole un `display: flex;` al .card además de `align-self: flex-start;` en el .button.  No es que quede perfecto, pero mejora algo.

Answer (score 0):

Encierro los textos de las cards en parrafos para poder manejarlos con css:

```
  <div class="cardcontainer">
    <div class="card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectet</p>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="balon.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, nam officiis eum hic praesentium natus adipisci voluptatem quasi rem, id sunt deleniti aliquid et corrupti sapiente consequuntur blanditiis? Voluptas, aperiam!</p>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="balon.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>provident autem quidem, odio, adipisci doloremque incidunt. Quisquam ratione doloribus autem.</p>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="balon.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

despues en CSS:

```
.cardcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative; /* no es estrictamente necesario que uses flex en las cards*/
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  box-shadow: var(--shadows);
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.card h2 {
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
  font-size: var(--font-size-2);
}

.button {
  position: absolute; /* con esto las propiedades top right bottom y left tomaran como referencia el padre (la card) */
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  bottom: 10px; /* el boton estara a 10px del borde inferior de la card*/
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; /* y left: 0 y right: 0 los usamos para centrar el boton horizontalmente*/
}

p{
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.button img {
  max-width: 20px;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

y fíjate que agregue algunas propiedades y tamaños relativos. De este modo el boton siempre queda en la misma posicion independientemente del tamaño del texto. Te recomiendo siempre colocar contenedores propios para el texto, puede ser una p o un div.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando display **flex** separamos los elementos con **justify-content: space-between**, pero ten en cuenta que esto dependerá del tamaño de tu contenido, si una *card* tiene mas contenido por ende se vera mas grande. Observa que dicha alineación se la asigno al contenedor padre **card**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
space-between
```

Los elementos se distribuyen uniformemente dentro del contenedor de alineación a lo largo del eje principal. El primer elemento está alineado con el borde de inicio principal y el último elemento está alineado con el borde de extremo principal.

```css
.cardcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  /*UTILIZAMOS DISPLA FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  /*HEIGHT MAS GRANDE PARA APRECIAR LA ALINEACION*/
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /*CON SPACE BETWEN HACEMOS LA SEPARACION DE LOS DOS ELEMENTOS*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  box-shadow: var(--shadows);
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.card h2 {
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
  font-size: var(--font-size-2);
}

.button {
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.button img {
  max-width: 20px;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
  <div class="card">
    {content1}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    {content2}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    {content3}
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/paw.png">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```